# Copying recursively

Tags: cp, scp

Why is it that when using cp -r or scp -r, if say you have a folder containing a large number of files but only byte-sized or a couple of kilobytes at most and you have another file the same size as that of the folder, then the former is many magnitude times slower than the latter?

Comment: Because data blocks in a file are a fixed size, and can be efficiently copied directly. Directory entries and inodes contain numerous details about the files within, which have to be meticulously updated into the existing structures. The directories also have to be locked frequently during updates to avoid concurrent changes from different processes.

Comment: Then can I overcome this by simply compressing the folder? (Decompression/Compression speed is not an issue)

Comment: Yes, if you compress it, you are turning it into a binary file, and getting rid of all the empty 'space' that each small file had. Say your file system is using 4096 bytes block size, that means an 8 byte file will occupy 4096 bytes, but compressed, depending on various things, it will occupy less than 8 bytes. The full compressed file will still round up in blocks to nearest 4096 block, but that will only impact a single chunk of the compressed file. Note however the real risk of data loss when compressing.

Comment: Also, look into rsync if you are doing this repeatedly from one directory to another, rsync is VERY fast and very efficient, and only changes updated bits/bytes in the destination directory. You can think of cp as a child's tricycle and rsync as a big commercial truck, so when large jobs are involved, rsync is often the much better choice because it's far more robust and powerful, and built for exactly this type of problem.

Comment: @Lizardx only as efficient as you've described when used across a network connection. You'll get very little asked improvement when copying between two filesystem points (apparently) on the same machine

Comment: Not the first time when run locally, no, but every subsequent time if repeated. Also, if cp fails or has to be stopped, you have to do it all over, but with rsync you can just start it again and it will takeover from where it stopped. I can think of few large operations where I'd prefer cp over rsync, pretty much none to be honest.

Comment: @Lizardx, no. You do not get any efficiency savings with `rsync` when copying between two (apparently) local points

Comment: Read what I said before you type. "Not the first time". All subsequent times the savings is massive, and far more accurate than cp. Apparently you've never used rsync, so that's ok, no problem.

Comment: You could tar and compress the directory first. Read `man tar`. Advantages: ONE file to copy, ONE set of file characteristics to transmit, compressed files are usually smaller. Disadvantages: overhead at both ends, UIDs and GIDs are copied numerically and may not match at the destination.